# Removing Duplicate Entries in Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

For Java practice, I am trying to create a method inside my EmployeesDirectory Class that:

- Removes Duplicate entries from the array
- The array should be the same length after removing duplicates
- Non-Empty entries should be making a contiguous sequence at the beginning of the array - and the actualNum should keep a record of the entries

Duplicate Means: **Same Name, Position and Salary**

Here is my Current Code:

I am unsure on how to implement this - any help would be appreciated

```
class EmployeeDirectory {

    private Employee dir[];
    private int size;
    private int actualNum;

    public EmployeeDirectory(int n) {
        this.size = n;
        dir = new Employee[size];
    }

    public boolean add(String name, String position, double salary) {
        if (dir[size-1] != null) {
            dir[actualNum] = new Employee(name, position, salary);
            actualNum++;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: removing duplicate entries !! You mean remove duplicate employees having the same name only ??

Comment: @MChaker they mean objects for which `a.equals(b) == true`

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather you did not write a distinct method for removing duplicates. If I were you, I would search for duplicates in `add` method and then instantly decide whether I need to add `Employee`.

Also, why don't you use `Sets` (link for [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)) instead of arrays for your purpose? Sets by their own definition disallow adding duplicates, so they seem to be appropriate as a solution

Comment: Set is not always useful because it breaks order of elements. But Set is useful when iterating the array to collect distinct objects.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, if you need the same order of elements as was the order of inserting them, there is a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to achieve this :)

Comment: With `LinkedHashSet` you lose ability to query item by index in O(1).

Comment: @SashaSalauyou that's a nice point, but what do you suggest to use instead of LinkedHashSet?

Comment: I suggest operating on initial array, shifting items left when duplicates are found, as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: What about [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)?

Comment: @remipod `TreeSet` access by value is O(log n), slower than `HashSet`.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou You should add your performance expectations to your question. A 'Set' would match the requirements mentioned in the question.  If you have considerations regarding performance, a LinkesHashSet provides constant-time performance for the basic operations add, contains and remove. Could you explain how you would provide a faster implementation?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, *Override* `equals` and `hashCode` methods in `Employee` class as follow

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if(this == other) return true;

    if(other == null || (this.getClass() != other.getClass())){
       return false;
    }

    Employee guest = (Employee) other;
    return  Objects.equals(guest.name, name) 
            && Objects.equals(guest.position, position) 
            && Objects.equals(guest.salary, salary); 
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] {
               name, 
               position, 
               salary
        });
}
```

Then you can use Stream API `distinct` method to remove duplicates

> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to
>   Object.equals(Object)) of this stream.

You can do it like so

```
Employee e1 = new Employee("John", "developer", 2000);
Employee e2 = new Employee("John", "developer", 2000);
Employee e3 = new Employee("Fres", "designer", 1500);

Employee[] allEmployees = new Employee[100];
allEmployees[0] = e1;
allEmployees[1] = e2;
allEmployees[2] = e3;

allEmployees = Arrays.asList(allEmployees).stream().distinct()
            .toArray(Employee[]::new);

Arrays.asList(allEmployees).forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:* (keeping both empty and non-empty entries)

```
John developer 2000.0
Fres designer 1500.0
null
```

Comment: @SashaSalauyou  What do you think of the above answer?

Comment: I think it is quite good (I love java 8 features too), but your `equals()` method is error-prone unless `name` and `position` are not guaranteed to be non-nulls.

Comment: and your `hashCode()` is very poor, usually it is combined by all non-static properties of the object.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou How about now?

Comment: if `this.name` is null you'll get NPE--that's what I've meant.

Comment: So how can i deal with this kind of problem? @SashaSalauyou

Comment: Use `Objects.equals(a, b)` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: well, I see you're attempting but now what if `this.name == null` and `other.name == null`? On practice, such objects are supposed to be equal if other properties are equal. But your code will return false.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I have not got the Employee class to verify my code, but try this:

```
void removeDuplicates() {
    int length = dir.length;
    HashSet set = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(dir));
    dir = new Employee[length];
    Employee[] temp = (Employee[]) set.toArray();
    for (int index = 0; index < temp.length; index++)
        dir[index] = temp[index];
}
```

The code must remain the size of array after deletion the duplicates. At the beginning of array there must be valid Employees, at the end - nulls.
And don't forget to add this at the beginning of your .java file

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.HashSet;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your task states as "remove duplicates from **array**" (i. e. you cannot use `ArrayList` or control when adding items), you can use the following approach:

```
public void removeDuplicates() {
    Set<Employee> d = new HashSet<>();  // here to store distinct items
    int shift = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i > dir.length; i++) {
        if (d.contains(dir[i])) {       // duplicate, shift += 1
            shift++;
        } else {                        // distinct
            d.add(dir[i]);              // copy to `d` set
            dir[i - shift] = dir[i];    // move item left
        }
    } 
    for (int i = d.size(); i < dir.length; i++)
        dir[i] = null;                  // fill rest of array with nulls

    actualNum = d.size();
}
```

Here, `shift` variable stores number of duplicates found in the array so far. Every distinct item is moved to `shift` positions left in order to make sequence continuous while keeping initial ordering. Then remaining items are altered to nulls.

To make hash-based collections work with `Employee` instances correctly, you also need to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods as follows:

```
public class Employee {

    //...

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, position, salary);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (!o.getType().equals(this.getType()) return false;
        Employee e = (Employee) o;
        return Objects.equals(e.name, name) 
            && Objects.equals(e.position, position) 
            && Objects.equals(e.salary, salary); // or e.salary == salary, if it primitive type
    }
}
```

Comment: Assigning single character as a name for a reference is a bad practice. Reference names should be meaningful. Also, you probably did not get what the Sets are. Sets CAN NOT contain equal objects.

Comment: *"You probably did not get what the Sets are"*--sorry, I cannot continue discussion is a such abrupt manner...

Comment: I did not mean to offend you, but Set itself "skips" all the Objects that it already contains. At this point your code does not make sense. Read docs. Sorry

Comment: Good approach using `Hashset` to store distinct items +1. But  the OP question said this `Duplicate Means: Same Name, Position and Salary` and no same object reference?

Comment: @MChaker just added `hashCode()` and `equals()` overrides.